# Is it possible to make consoles full screen?

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, console, fullscreen

Is it possible on to switch a console to full-screen in Windows XP on a single monitor? Meaning on a dual monitor that only the left (or right) screen displays the console while the other one remains on Windows. By *full-screen* I mean true-fullscreen mode, not just resizing (maximize) to fill in the screen.

Comment: Windows Vista/7 or XP?

Comment: Windows XP (no choice in office)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 7 (and I believe Vista) doesn't support the full-screen feature for MS-DOS or Command Prompt console. It doesn't even allow full-screen when using the Command Prompt via Windows 7's Windows XP Mode. On Windows XP, it can be set to full screen via <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> or right-clicking the console title bar and selecting Full Screen.

A possible workaround on Windows 7: With Command Prompt open, right click the console title bar, then select *Properties*. Within the *Layout* tab, you can adjust the width and height. My suggestion is: Adjust only the width to match the width of your screen. Once the adjustments are made, double click the console title bar. Using this workaround gives it the closest full-screen effect that can be achieved.

Comment: This is correct.  The newer display drivers no longer suppport full screen console programs.  Now if you switch back to XP drivers. ..

Comment: `On Windows XP, it can be set to full screen via Alt + Enter or right-clicking the console title bar and selecting Full Screen.`   It might not work without the right driver.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to make consoles full screen?

Why yes; yes it is, but only up to Windows XP, it is [no longer supported in Vista and up](https://superuser.com/questions/314675/what-are-the-requirements-for-fullscreen-consoles-in-windows-7). You can get basic full-screen functionality with just <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, but for better compatibility and to resolve [some issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa460102.aspx#xpesp2rnmuiissues), you can install the [*Full screen video driver for console*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa939673.aspx):

1. Open the *Add Hardware* applet in the Control Panel
2. Click Next, then select *Already Connected*
3. Select *Add a new hardware device* at the bottom of the list
4. Choose *Manually Select (Advanced)*
5. Select *Show All Devices*
6. Under *Manufacturer*, select **Microsoft Corporation**
7. Under *Model*, select **Full screen video driver for console**
8. Next, Next, Finish (reboot if prompted)

Now you can press <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd> in console windows to switch them to fullscreen mode (it displays in whichever monitor is set to the *primary*).

**NB:** this works best for the command-prompt (ie, text-mode) while graphics-mode games and such tend to have problems (eg hanging). If you want to get games working in full-screen (or at all), then you need to use [various hacks](http://www.google.com/search?q=dos%20games%20in%20xp) to get them to work such as using the [`nolfb`](http://advsys.net/ken/build.htm)<sup>[[1]](http://vogons.zetafleet.com/viewtopic.php?t=467)</sup> and [`cli2nop`](http://buildxp.deathmask.net/)<sup>[[2]](http://vogons.zetafleet.com/viewtopic.php?t=31)</sup> tools and [VDMSound](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vdmsound/).

Comment: run `devmgmt.msc` menu `action`, `add legacy hadrdware` for me in windows7 ***x64***. But ***I have no "Full screen video driver" there***. Also I have ***no `fsvga.inf` on my system drive C:***

Comment: @naxa, because it is [no longer supported in Windows Vista](http://superuser.com/questions/314675/what-are-the-requirements-for-fullscreen-consoles-in-windows-7) and up; it only works up to Windows XP (which is what this question is about).

Comment: ah. there was some hackery where you could supposedly turn full screen on 7 back on, most likely due to a windows bug but I cannot find it.

Comment: @naxa, the closest you can get is to simply maximize the console window; there’s no way (that I’ve been able to find in my quest) to make it actually fullscreen in 7 like you could in XP (where the screen actually changes to text-mode). ◔̯◔

Answer (score 0):

[ShiftWindow](http://grismar.net/shiftwindow/) : Resize an app window to get pseudo fullscreen, this will hide titlebars and window borders for msot applications, you may need to actually increase cmd.exe window width from the properties dialog first to be effective.

I haven't tested the above but this might work, good luck :)

Comment: How is DualMon actually related to having a console full-screen on only one monitor? ShiftWindow may kind of resize to fill in the screen but that seem to be for EVE only.

Comment: @Wernight ShiftWindow will work for any application, you just need to define a Rule with proper window title.

Answer (score 0):

[Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) has a custom terminal that will go "true" full screen.

By default only the scrollbar on the right will be visible. You can turn those off in options if you desire, and also enable block cursor or whatever other flavor you like. It's a completely custom Terminal implementation, not a regular windows window console app.

*To toggle cygwin terminal fullscreen mode simply press `Alt+Enter`*

Incidentally the cygwin terminal also supports transparency, if you like to have your log or output in a separate terminal underneath your working terminal, like you can on most linux distros.