# How can I maximize the window of a command line application?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, fullscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to make consoles full screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/329747/is-it-possible-to-make-consoles-full-screen)

I have Windows XP installed on my laptop and can't maximize the window of my 16bit application.

When I try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, it doesn't show as full-screen. I tried the options in its "Properties" tab, but that didn't work either.

I have another copy of this application installed on my PC with no problem of maximizing it to full-screen.

Comment: Possible Duplication: http://superuser.com/q/329747/20433

Answer (score 1):

Try using [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/). The main problem is that from Windows 7 onwards, support for 16bit applications is reduced and hence the problems.

Comment: ok I'm going to read it :)

Comment: The questioner is using Windows XP, however.

Comment: earlier the tag said said windows 7 so got little confused